# How to apply map() when working with a batched Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a timeseries Dataset using `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array`.
According to the docs, it returns a `tf.data.Dataset` instance.
I also pass the batch size argument when calling the `timeseries_dataset_from_array` function, so my dataset is a BatchDataset.
I am using map on this batched Dataset (`ds`), passing `my_fun`.
Data in the code below is a pandas dataframe containing continuous timesteps.

What does the `my_fun` function expect as input parameters - aka what does it apply on each iteration? Whole batches of shape (samples, sequence_length, features) or a single element of shape (None, sequence_length, features)?

I am confused because when I print the single argument that I define in my `my_fun` function, it yields a shape of (None, None, features), but I cannot inspect it further...

My code is inspired from the TF tutorial (see split_window function)
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

```py
def split_window(self, features):
   inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
   labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
   if self.label_columns is not None:
     labels = tf.stack(
         [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in 
          self.label_columns],
             axis=-1)

   # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
   # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
   inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
   labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

   return inputs, labels

data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
ds = timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=24,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=32)
 
ds = ds.map(split_window)
```

Comment: Without all the information about your function and your dataset it is hard to help you. But one thing you can try is to enable eager execution, which seems to be disabled in your case. If it is enabled, then you should be able to print the tensors with their actual values and shapes.

Comment: i use tf  2, so its enabled by default, but still doesnt yielf the actual values. i think because it only outputs the graph results

Comment: If you add your function code to the question I can try to check why the values are not printed.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: What happens if you do print(features.numpy()) at the beginning of split_window? Does it produce an error message?

Comment: numpy() throws an error

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I am not able to answer the whole question, but I can tell you why you are not able to print anything inside your function. As you can read in the documentation of tf.data.Dataset, a call of dataset.map() will execute the function that is mapped always in graph mode and not in eager mode, which does not allow any printing. For further information, check https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map

In the same section, it is described what to do if you want to use python code inside such a function, which is using tf.py_function(). I have not worked with this yet, but it seems like you should be able to call it in the following way:

```
ds = ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func=split_window, inp=[self, x], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.float32)))
```

This then should give you the necessary tools to find the answer to your question.

Comment: this doesnt work for me. but i think i figured it out.. split window accepts batches